# System.Threading.Timer freezing computer

Tags: c#, performance, crash

I am working on creating a game, and I have a pathfinding function that takes about 100 ms. I have 5 enemies, each with this function in the contstructor:

```
newPath = new System.Threading.Timer((e) => {
  getNewPath(); //The function that takes ~100 ms
}, null, 0, 5000);
```

Now, I am using System.Threading.Timer at an earlier point in the program (to run once every 50 ms just for a step function, to update positions and such). That one works fine, but if I run this function (don't forget I have 5 enemies, so it's running 5 times every 5 seconds), my whole entire computer just freezes. Now I don't have a crappy computer (it's not the best, but it's plenty good for what i'm using it for), so I don't know what the issue is. Even if all timers run one after the other (which they shouldn't do, they should run at the same time), the most it should take is 500ms (or half a second), yet it completely kills my computer, to the point where my mouse doesn't move, I can't Ctrl-Alt-Del, and I have to just hold the power button until it turns off.

I tested putting a simple print function in place of the getNewPath(), and it worked flawlessly and as expected, so I don't really know what the issue is.

My questions are:

1. What is causing my computer to lock up to the point of having to hold the power button.
2. Is there something I can use other than System.Threading.Timer that will give me the desired result without completely killing my computer? (Being able to run this function up to ~20 times at once, since it's an MMO and there could potentially be hundreds of enemies that it needs to do pathfinding updates on).

Thanks!

Comment: It might be hard to answer without seeing the code in getNewPath. It's unlikely that the timer is slowing the computer, and very likely the code in getNewPath is.

Comment: @hatchet, It's a simple A* pathfinding algorithm

Comment: @hatchet https://pastebin.com/iF6f8eqi

Comment: Although I don't see why what is in the code would be slowing my computer down THAT much. It should take 100ms no matter what, no?

Comment: Also, are you sure you're not creating a bunch of these timers and never turning them off?

Comment: @hatchet The only place I create it is in the constructor, and I tried it with print statements and works exactly as expected, only 5 prints every 5 seconds.

Comment: Whislt theoretically a timer should not lead to you not being able to Ctrl-Alt-Del, creating a timer that executes many times a second to update objects pathfinding may not be the way to go.  Generally, you don't want to update everything in your game in one go, rather you update a few per frame and repeat the process over successive frames until all are processed.  This is known as _deferred processing_ and is a tactic used in many games with large number of items such as _Cities: Skylines_

Comment: @MickyD thanks for the info, I just worry that if I do this, when I get a large number of enemies, the pathfinding will start to take quite a long time (if I do it one at a time it'll be 20-30 seconds to get through all of them, assuming I only have 200-300 enemies, which is a pretty low estimate of what it could be). How would I go about solving this issue?

Comment: Does the computer instantly go to a halt ? Or it takes some time to slow the system down?

Comment: @XiaoguoGe well it works fine for the 5 second delay (since it takes 5 seconds to run once), then it slows down massively (almost instantly to the point of not usable, and within seconds it's at a point of the mouse being frozen). So not *instantly*, but very, very quickly.

Comment: @user183106 That is not what I said.  What I told you is a **real world technique** used by AAA game studios.  I suggest you watch the Unity3D conferences at YouTube

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the code inside getNewPath(), it is impossible to even guess the  reason. And it is hard to believe that is only **a simple A* path finding algorithm**

Here are some points to start the investigation

1. What is the CPU usage rate before halt happens? What it is the rate when it happens? Which process has the highest rate?
2. What is the disk, network, memory usage rate?
3. Beside the above, does getNewPath consume other resources?
4. You can print 5 messages. But are they printed before/inside/after getNewPath
5. Do you have source code for getNewPath? Can you modify code in getNewPath?
6. Is getNewPath thread safe? Does it create more threads?

There are probably more things to look at. But these should be enough to get you started. And they are necessary for anyone to give meaning suggestions.

Comment: Is this an answer to this specific question or a general answer on  how to _debug_?  I see alot of questions there too, more fitting as a **comment**